# Eventbrite API get full description

Tags: eventbrite

When using an eventbrite api end point e.g.
https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/11111/?token=xxx

I only get the summary description  e.g.

```
"description": {
    "text": "Short description", 
    "html": "Short description"
},
```

Is there a way to get the full description?

Answer (score 3):

That is strange... I ran a call to the API and I received a full description.

*Note: The description was on multiple lines.

Can you share the event_id this is happening to?

*Also, Note: I am using iTerm, Python with the requests package, and pretty print package(pprint) to make my calls to the API. Could this be a settings issue with the tool you are using to make the calls?

Comment: I'm using PHP but even testing via  the url
https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/53816433401/?status=live&token=

It happens on all events as far as I can see

I was wondering if there is an undocumented expand option - but ..

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I see now that you are using the new event creation dashboard. It is only bringing over the "Summary"... correct?

Comment: OK - here is the issue
Using the old UI  edit-event -you get one long description - this allows html etc
Using the new UI ( can't see it is optional - I guess based on when the account was created? ) you get Design - which has Summary * and Write a Description about your event, Summary is non HMTL and 140 chars.   

The API only provides the Summary *  and appears no way to get the html / full description.

Hope that helps - does that mean the API is behind the UI? Will it get updated?

Comment: Yes, the API is behind the UI and it is a known issue at Eventbrite. You can opt out of the new UI. You just need to contact the API support team. You can do that here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/eventbrite-api

Comment: Thanks, but opting out isn't really an option as a maintain a WordPress plugin that integrates Eventbrite by API and hence has hundreds if not thousands of users which I can't really advise all new user to opt out.   I look forward to hearing about the fix time line - any where I can keep up to date with that?

Answer (score 3):

This is mentioned about the [retrieve event](https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/reference/event/retrieve-an-event) endpoint.

> Note: If the Event being retrieved was created using the new version of Create, then you may notice that the Event’s description field is now being used to hold the event summary. To retrieve your event’s fully-rendered HTML description, you will need to make an additional API call to retrieve the Event's full HTML description.

So, to fetch an events description, use this endpoint:
https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/reference/event/retrieve/retrieve-event-html-description

Answer (score 0):

This is the endpoint, in case someone gets here after Jul 2020 https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/event_id/description/

Comment: You will have to explain that.

Comment: Please explain the relevance of July 2020  - that end point has been around at lease a year. As mentioned in other comments.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and found this on the official documentation: [Retrieve full HTML description](https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/reference/event-description/retrieve/retrieve-full-html-description).
The reason is that, as mentioned in Sheldon's answer (and [here in docs](https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/reference/event/retrieve/retrieve-full-html-description)):

> To retrieve your event’s fully-rendered HTML description, you will need to make an additional API call to retrieve the Event's full HTML description.